# Display <input type="file"> filename

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to collect and prepend the filename of the selected input file into a table:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" id="upload-modal-button">
    <span class="btn btn-small btn-success fileinput-button">
      <span>Browse</span>
      <input type="file" name="file_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid" id="image-table">
  <div class="span12">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="upload-list">
      <thead>
        <td>Filename</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
      </thead>
      <tr id="filelist"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
  $('#filelist').prepend('<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>');
});
```

But I cant get the filename to display in the table.

Comment: [A stripped down version of this seems to work.](http://jsfiddle.net/H7kaD/)

Comment: [Working here](http://jsbin.com/enocib/1/edit).

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/H7kaD/1/) for me in IE9, FF13 and Chrome22.

Comment: Alright must be something else then. Doing this in a twitter-bootstrap modal. Thanks for validating it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you work with ´jquery 1.8´, the selector ´type=file´ works correctly but if you work with ´jquery 1.6´ this selector will not work.
the correct way is to use this type of selectors:

```
$('input[type="file"]')
```

or, you can use this type selector, with class:

HTML:

```
<input class="input-type-file" type="file" name="file_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

JS:

```
$('.input-type-file')
```

Comment: Is this an issue specific to file inputs?

Comment: @tomaroo I don't know, to me the correct way is to include the quotes, is that earlier versions had problems with double quote or single quote. can be improved are now able to exclude the quotes